# ViewPager fragment locale update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, locale

I have a ViewPager with 4 fragments, on one of its fragment I am giving option to user to choose language, once selected text on the current fragment should be updated to reflect chosen language. None of the content in my layout xml files is hardcoded but populated from strings.xml file. I have localized strings.xml files.

Below is the algorithm used:

1. Store language selected in preferences
2. Update locale
3. Detach - attach fragment from parent activity

Here is the code:

**LangSelectionFragment.java** (Current Fragment)

```
@OnClick({R.id.english_radio_button, R.id.hindi_radio_button})
    public void onLanguageSelection(RadioButton radioButton) {
        switch (radioButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.english_radio_button:
                updateLocaleForEnglish();
                break;
            case R.id.hindi_radio_button:
                updateLocaleForHindi();
                break;
        }
    }

    private  void updateLocaleForEnglish() {
        LocaleManager.updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(EnglishISOCode, getActivity());
        LocaleManager.updateLocale(EnglishISOCode,getResources());
        localRefreshActor.refreshFragmentsLocale();
    }

    private void updateLocaleForHindi() {
        LocaleManager.updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(HindiISOCode, getActivity());
        LocaleManager.updateLocale(HindiISOCode,getResources());
        localRefreshActor.refreshFragmentsLocale();
    }
```

**OnBoardingActivity.java** (Parent Activity / localeRefreshActor)

```
@Override
    public void refreshFragmentsLocale() {
        Fragment currentFragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()); // returns LangSelectionFragment
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.remove(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**LocaleManager** (Stores chosen language in preferences, updates locale)

```
public class LocaleManager {
    private static final String AppLangIsoCodeKey = "appLangIso";

    public static void updateLangIsoCodeInPreferences(String languageIsoCode, Context context) {
        PreferencesManager.initializeInstance(context);
        PreferencesManager preferencesManager = PreferencesManager.getInstance();
        preferencesManager.setStringValue(languageIsoCode, AppLangIsoCodeKey);
    }

    public static String getLangFromPreferences(Context context) {
        PreferencesManager.initializeInstance(context);
        PreferencesManager preferencesManager = PreferencesManager.getInstance();
        return  preferencesManager.getStringValueForKey(AppLangIsoCodeKey);
    }

    public static void updateLocale(String languageIsoCode, Resources res) {
        if(languageIsoCode != null && languageIsoCode.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            return;
        }
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageIsoCode);
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
}
```

**Problem is -**

> It is not updating text on my current fragment as per language
>   selected :(

Am I missing anything over here? Please suggest.

Comment: why are you trying to override the system's behavior?

Comment: I understand your point, but it is client's requirement. He is ok with overwriting default behavior unless it leads to app rejection from app store.

Comment: lol, those crazy clients